# Loading dynamic imageviews in loop in Android creating gaps

Tags: android

I am reading data from a SOAP service and then using that data to load images from the res folder locally. I am using a loop because there will always be six images being loaded. This is my code :

```
final TableLayout tblLay = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.lottotl);
final LayoutParams params = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
              LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

  for(int i=2;i<9;i++) { 

    final ImageView image = new ImageView(LastDraw.this);
    image.setLayoutParams(trparams);
    image.setMaxHeight(20);
    image.setMaxWidth(20);

    String imgName = "img_" + split[i].substring(split[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", getPackageName()); 
    image.setImageResource(id);


    row2.setLayoutParams(params);
    row2.addView(image);
}
tblLay.addView(row2);
```

The issue I am having is that there is a gap between the first image and the consecutive images.

It looks like this (each number representing an image):

1.........23456

I am thinking it has to do with the layout of the row in the tablelayout, I could be wrong.

Thank you

Anyone?

Comment: i think that the first column stretches by default or something like this, saw it some days ago here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out ... feel kind of stupid but, I learnt something! I load a textview into the first row and then the imageviews into the second row. The textview is in the first column and its width is making the first column stretch ... THAT is why there is a gap.